# Different between functions and regression models in R?

Tags: r, regression

I'm really confused about regression models and functions in R. Here is my problem. I'm using the PLS package to make a model like Y~x. To do that I have to use 'plsr':

```
model=plsr(Y~X,ncomp=10,data=df1,center=TRUE, scale=TRUE, validation="LOO")
```

I couldn't find the source of the 'plsr' in the PLS source code but in the help document it says it refers to 'mvr{pls}' which I could find it. first is 'plsr' a function or model.. in the R terminology? is it built in R? and how does it refer to 'mvr' function in pls package?

Thanks

Comment: `plsr` is a function. `Y~X` is your model. It’s not builtin, it is part of a separate package (“PLS”). For more information on the connection between `plsr` and `mvr`, read the documentation (e.g. [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pls/docs/mvr)).

Comment: `pls` is a function. As far as I know, "model" is more of a statistical or mathematical term than an R term, but the formula "Y~X" can be read "model Y by X." From the help page of `lm`: the formula (here Y~X) is "a symbolic description of the model to be fitted."

Comment: Thanks, Maybe the Y~X term is misleading here, my question is if 'plsr' is a function where is its source code? Its not in the pls package source.